# Regular expression with R

Tags: regex, r

```
> name = '645te5.78d'
```

I am looking for a function that can get rid of the dot and anything that follows in my variable `name`.

```
> new_fun(name)
> name
'645te5'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is a general case that

There exist only one dot and you want to get the first part. Maybe you `strsplit` instead.

```
unlist(strsplit(name, '\\.'))[1]
```

Comment: Also this is one case where you don't really need a regular expression so you can do: `unlist(strsplit(name, '.', fixed = TRUE))[1]`. It is faster if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 3):

`sub` should work:

```
sub('\\..*', '', name)
```